# Array Clone doesn't work

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, clone

what is wrong with my code?

in the main method i am doing this:

```
int [] test=new int[48];

test=etable(Right[]).clone();
```

What i want is, that the 'test' array is exactly the same like the output of the 'etable' method.

my method called 'etable':

```
public static int [] etable(int [] right){
int [] blabla=new int[48];
...
return blabla[]
}
```

Thanks for your advise

Comment: Everything is wrong with your code. It doesn't compile and the argument passed to `etable()` is ignored.

Comment: Whats wrong, even i dont know:). Actually i dont know, what are you saying. Looking at the code, i am not sure if there are typos or you are not getting the desired output. What is the problem?

Comment: The real problem (from my perspective) is that you haven't properly explained what the code is *supposed* to do.  If you don't do that, we can't really tell you how to do *that*.  (OK ... so maybe it is just an artificial example.  But in that case, why even bother with all of the stuff about `etable` and so on?  It only makes the Question unnecessarily long-winded and confusing!!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is wrong with my code?

This line is a compilation error:

```
    test = etable(Right[]).clone();
```

If `right` (or `Right`) is a variable (declared with type `int[]`), then you should write the method call like this:

```
    test = etable(right).clone();
```

If `Right` is a type, then that is not the correct syntax for creating an array.  (And judging from how you have written the `etable` method, you should not be passing it a new array.)

The second problem is that this sequence doesn't make sense:

```
    int test[] = new int[48];
    test = etable(...).clone();
```

You are allocating an array of 48 elements ... and then throwing it away by assigning a different array reference to the `test` variable.

The third problem is that the `clone()` is most likely redundant anyway.  Your `etable` method is allocating a new array (in `blabla`) and returning it.  The calling code is then *copying* the new array.  Unless the `etable` saves the reference to the `blabla` array somewhere, the copying step doesn't achieve anything.

The final problem is that if `Right` really is a variable name, then that is a serious Java style violation.  In Java a variable name should NOT start with an upper-case letter.

Answer (score 1):

Use for instance `Arrays.copy()`:

```
int[] tmp = etable(whatever);
int[] test = Arrays.copy(tmp, 0, tmp.length);
```

As to your original code, this, for instance:

```
test = ebtable(Right[]).clone();
```

is not legal Java (what is `Right` anyway?).